# how to generate random images in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
function computerRandom(){
var compImgs = ["rock1Computer.png", "paper1Computer.png", "scissors1Computer.png"];
var compRps =  Math.floor(Math.random() * compImgs);

const showComp = document.canvas.src = compImgs[compRps];
var showImg = compImgs[showComp];
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="playerBtn">
    <button type="button" onclick="showPRock()" onclick="computerRandom()"  id="rockBtn">Rock</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPPaper()" onclick="computerRandom()" id="paperBtn">Paper</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPScissors()" onclick="computerRandom()" id="scissorsBtn">Scissors</button>
</div>
```

this is the stack overflow editor that shos the code this way the format is fine.
i made a function to generate a random image, but it isn't working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `Math.random() * compImgs`: think about this bit. Can you really multiply a number by an array or is there a _property_ of that array that you should be multiplying with instead?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you should change your `var compRps =  Math.floor(Math.random() * compImgs);` to `var compRps =  Math.floor(Math.random() * compImgs.length);`.

As Andy said in comments, your trying to multiply it by array instead of number of elements it contains.

Comment: function computerRandom(){
    var compImgs = ["rock1Computer.png", "paper1Computer.png", "scissors1Computer.png"];
    var compRps =  Math.floor(Math.random() * compImgs.length);
    var showImg = compImgs[compRps];
    
    showImg.style.display = "block";
};                  i changed the code a little, so that it becomes visible bul it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You should check your console log (dev tools (F12)) to see if there are errors. @Hamzacreator

Answer (score 0):

Your try has a lot of mistakes. I write out a whole code for you and explain it here.

HTML:

```
<div class="playerBtn">
    <button type="button" onclick="showPRock()" onclick="computerRandom()"  id="rockBtn">Rock</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPPaper()" onclick="computerRandom()" id="paperBtn">Paper</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPScissors()" onclick="computerRandom()" id="scissorsBtn">Scissors</button>
</div>
<img src = "rock1Computer.png" alt = "Computer chooses rock!"id = "imgrock">
<img src = "paper1Computer.png" alt = "Computer chooses paper!"id = "imgpaper">
<img src = "scissors1Computer.png" alt = "Computer chooses scissors!"id = "imgscissors">
```

Your html is mostly fine. I also added imgs assuming "rock1Computer.png", "paper1Computer.png" and "scissors1Computer.png" are actual paths

Javascript

```
function computerRandom(){
var compImgs = ["rock1Computer.png", "paper1Computer.png", "scissors1Computer.png"];
var compRps =  Math.floor(Math.random() * compImgs.length);

const showComp = compImgs[compRps];
var showImg = document.getElementById("img" + showComp.split("1")[0]);
showImg.style.display = "block"
};
```

we take a random string from the array then we take the characters before 1 (either rock paper or scissors) and we make them visible

CSS:

```
[id^="img"] {
    display: none;
}
```

we hide the img elements from before

This answer should work

Comment: ok, well i just treind out code and when I clicked the button It didn't work and I'm really confused.

Comment: are scissors1Computer.png, rock1Computer.png and paper1Computer.png actual filepaths? @Hamzacreator